# Invoicing - calling multiple pages of Api and concatinating the results

Tags: c#, rest

I have the following code: It works completely as expected, but I feel there is a better way to refactor it out.

The flow is as follows:

1. Call the end point with 1 page
2. Get the total number of results.
3. If total count of items more than `itemsPerPage`.
4. Call the API more times till results from all pages are returned, join them together as single invoice list
5. Append with initial request and send back.

Do I need `GetAllInvoices` function? Reason it is kept there is because I believe the responsibility of calling each pages of API does not belong to main function.

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Invoice>> GetAllInvoicesAsync()
{
    const string endPoint = @"foo/{0}/invoices?pageNum={1}&itemsPerPage={2}";
    const int itemsPerPage = xxx;
    InvoiceCollection response = await _apiClient
        .GetAsync<InvoiceCollection>(string.Format(endPoint, _apiClient.OrgId, 1, itemsPerPage));

    if (response?.TotalCount > itemsPerPage)
    {
        var allInvoices = (await GetAllInvoices(endPoint,response.TotalCount, itemsPerPage))
            .SelectMany(i => i.Invoices?? Enumerable.Empty<Invoice>());
        response.Invoices = (response.Invoices ?? Enumerable.Empty<Invoice>()).Concat(allInvoices);
    }

    return response?.Invoices; 
}

private async Task<List<InvoiceCollection>> GetAllInvoices(string endPoint,int totalCount, int itemsPerPage)
{
    var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalCount / (double)itemsPerPage);
    var tasks = new List<Task<InvoiceCollection>>();

    for (int currentPage = 2; currentPage<=totalPages;currentPage++)
    {
        tasks.Add(_apiClient
            .GetAsync<InvoiceCollection>(string.Format(endPoint, _apiClient.OrgId, currentPage, itemsPerPage)));
    }
    var response = new List<InvoiceCollection>(await Task.WhenAll(tasks));
    return response;
}

public class InvoiceCollection
 {
     [JsonProperty("foo")]
     public IEnumerable<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
     public int TotalCount { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Updated the title

Comment: I think @BCdotWEB means that the title should mention invoicing and that the current title can be asked within the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an assumption of getting a mix of return one or more values. You need to favor collection over single value return; because treating it as a collection would make things easier to deal with.

So, you can get rid of `GetAllInvoices` and adjust `GetAllInvoicesAsync` to something like this :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Invoice>> GetAllInvoicesAsync()
{
    const string endPoint = @"foo/{0}/invoices?pageNum={1}&itemsPerPage={2}";
    const int itemsPerPage = xxx;
    int pageNumber = 1; 
    int iterationCount = 0;

    var tasks = new List<Task<InvoiceCollection>>();

    var isFirstRound = true;

    do
    {   
        var response = await _apiClient.GetAsync<InvoiceCollection>(string.Format(endPoint, _apiClient.OrgId, pageNumber, itemsPerPage));

        if(isFirstRound) 
        { 
            iterationCount = response?.TotalCount <= itemsPerPage ? response?.TotalCount : (int) Math.Ceiling(totalPageItems / (double)itemsPerPage);
            isFirstRound = false;
        }

        tasks.Add(response);

        pageNumber++;
    } 
    while(pageNumber <= iterationCount)

    var invoiceResponseList = new List<InvoiceCollection>(await Task.WhenAll(tasks));

    var invoiceCollection = invoiceResponseList.SelectMany(i => i.Invoices ?? Enumerable.Empty<Invoice>());

    return invoiceCollection?.Invoices; 
}
```